# Failed to attach to process ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, ios-simulator

I've really tried everything. Restarting Xcode, deleting map in derivedData and in application support/iOS simulator, reseting the simulator, restarting my mac, cleaning and building the project.

All other projects are running fine on both simulator and device. This project used to work but I was changing some settings in info and build phases but dont believe this is the problem.

Any fix for this error? When i run for simulator I get the error:

> failed to attach to process ID 0

And when i build for device it says:

> error: failed to launch '/Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXXX-ddmwyymhinfkgycuuuhjmmmkivcm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XXXXXXXX.app/XXXXXXXX' -- No such file or directory (/Users/XXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXXXX-ddmwyymhinfkgycuuuhjmmmkivcm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XXXXXXXX.app/XXXXXXX)

Comment: No its not a duplicate because all those solutions arent working

Comment: In a situation like this, typically one would look back to review what's been changed.  In your case, you made changes to the settings.  Please list the settings you've changed.

Comment: fixed by going back to a created snapshot